# When using JavaScript, how do I create code that automatically clicks a link and opens it in a new tab?

Tags: javascript

When using JavaScript, how do I create code that automatically clicks 2 links and opens it in a new tab?
If there is a link like, https://www.google.com/ how do I make it so that the code clicks the link every 3 minutes in a infinite loop?
Mine only clicks one link how do make it so that it changes it to open google.com and bing.com?
    var i = 0;

```
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.open("http://www.google.com"); 
        i++;
        if (i < 20) { 
            myLoop(); 
        }
    }, 180000)
}

myLoop();
```

This was my code.
But, it does not work.

Comment: Do you want it to *click a link*, or do you want it to *visit a url*?  Your question asks how to click a link, but your code simply visits a url.

Comment: `if (i < 20) { 20` this line wont compile

Comment: @fmodos: It'll compile. The `20` clearly shouldn't be there, but it'll get a semicolon and be a harmless numeric literal statement.

Comment: Your code should work just fine as long as you're invoking the `myLoop()` function and you don't have a popup blocker.

Comment: Well im curious as to how you are not going to aggravate your users with this constant iteration. New window would be `window.open('url','_blank');` which _blank is default but could be stopped by popup blocker for more info here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: are you sure that it does not work, or does your browser just block it? you will see in the right upper corner (in chrome its in the address bar)

Comment: This code should open `google.com` in a new window every three minutes for an hour. Note: it won't open the window right away--only after 3 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Following your question what you seem to be searching for is this:

```
function myLoop() {
   window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank"); 
}

window.setInterval(myLoop, 3*60*1000);
```

I advise you to have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) MDN documentation.

Now, about your code, you made some simple mistakes, that I believe will be cleared out after you the read MDN documentation (above), but just in case, I'll give you some help on that:

```
var i = 0;

// your function sets a timeout
function myLoop() {

    // here
    setTimeout(function () {

        // and here it opens the link on the new tab, almost, you forgot the "_blank"
        window.open("http://www.google.com"); 

        i++;

        // but this code bellow also calls myLoop, which will set a timeout
        // again, as long as 'i' is lower than 20.
        if (i < 20) { 
            myLoop(); 
        }
    }, 180000)
}

// this code calls your function (obviously)
myLoop();
```

**Update**

I used `window.setTimeout` instead of [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) by mistake.
Please see my updated answer.

By looking at your code, I think that what you were trying to achieve is the same logic that is implemented by `window.setInterval`.

Although `window.setInterval` and `window.setTimeout` seem similar, the first calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function,
while the second, only calls that function once after the specified time delay.

Comment: Um...just a heads up: 3 * 1000 is three *seconds*, not minutes.

Comment: @AlexMorrise Thanks, I'll fix it, I understood 3 secs.

Comment: @EasyBB Yes I know, but when programming I try to be as descriptive as I can, since that, could not be obvious to everyone the default values of all functions. Also being this a browser level language, implementations from one browser to another could change in terms of defaults, not a very common case, but can happen, so I prefer to specify in most cases.

Comment: @EasyBB Just because it's clearly obvious for you, that does not mean that is obvious for everybody else. So, seeing things this way, I believe my answer helps the one in need to better understand the problem, isn't this the all purpose of StackOverflow? If you believe you can do better, go ahead and make your answer, it's a better effort than stay here posting useless comments.